# Minecraft, Custom Libraries and LWJGL

Tags: lwjgl, minecraft, java

What would be my best bet for trying to roll my own libraries when I want to launch Minecraft on an ARM device? Standard Mojang repositories only have x86 versions of LWJGL in particular, and trying to overwrite the copies in .minecraft/libraries with armhf version triggered a corrupt file error and a redownload cycle with the x86 version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to run Minecraft on mobile? Correct me if this is incorrect, Because LWJGL is already compatible with ARM, it doesn't even care which CPU  it is running on (e.g AMD CPUs are ARM) because the two main APIs it is using (Java and OpenGL) both don't either - It even supports all OSs because of this too, it's just preferred that you use 64-bit libraries on 64-bit systems for speed purposes, you can always just use 32-bit even.

I would also like to clear up that Mojang did not make LWJGL so searching their repositories isn't the place to look. Plus if it were possible to simply change the natives they would have done that instead of make it again..

Comment: I know that, but Minecraft has it's own older versions of dependancies that if I try to overwrite or correct for, it senses something is wrong, and downloads the faulty dependency again in order to try and correct for it. I think my best bet is to try and hotwire the Minecraft launcher since it's the one insisting on these particular files, but I wanted to make sure before I started tearing things up.

Comment: I would never suggest using older libraries or natives for any program/game than what it is currently using, expected methods and variables may not exist - which is my guess as to why the launcher insists it wont work.